# oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: oracle.xdo11g.xqxp.XQException: FORG0001

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, report, business-intelligence

Oracle BI throws this exception, in data model it runs and gives data with no problem

Comment: I think you have to give more context. This happens when you do what? This is stackoverflow. We want to see some code you run that gives you that errror.

Comment: The error appears when I want to run BI report, "We want to see some code you run that gives you that errror" - there are more than 10 of them,reports and scripts, I want to hear general suggestion about the error, I think the problem is not in script, hope so

Comment: The above are not oracle pl/sql errors. Sounds like the front-end cannot connect to the database.